# how to connect my backend with my frontend?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, frontend, backend, vercel

when I try to send the form filled out by my client to my server it gives me an error, from the site

```
Access to fetch at 'https://portfolio-backend-lovat.vercel.app/api/send-email' from origin 
https://www.ivancamassa.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`
```

I tried giving permissions via the backend with the cors package

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://www.ivancamassa.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
```

I should edit the vercel.json file?